# How emit/include a custom helper in view based on web.config setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-config

While, I can check web.config settings inside a razor view; i.e. if `<add key="UnobtrusiveJSEnabled==false" value="true" />` is set to true or false or null, but how to emit a custom helper, and script manager inside a razor view?

I want to include a custom `@HTML.MyCustom.DDL()` if `UnobtrusiveJSEnabled==false`

```
@if (System.Web.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnobtrusiveJSEnable"] == "false")
  {        
    // how to include the custom helper here?  
    @HTML.MyCustom.DDL();  // does not render to the view??
    @HTML.MyCustom.ScriptManager(); // does not render to the view??
  }
```

Comment: You are NOT checking `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` settings inside your If condition !

Comment: @Shyju the farming.. was a quick edit/example, I'll edit it out.